# Gradle - get jar and native lib from Maven (snapshots) repository

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

There is jar in https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/com/oracle/avatar-js/0.10.25-SNAPSHOT/

and dll in https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/com/oracle/libavatar-js-win-x64/0.10.25-SNAPSHOT/

And *build.gradle* to get those dependencies even for jar.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.oracle.avatar-js:avatar-js:0.10.+"
}
```

with error

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.oracle.avatar-js:avatar-js:0.10.+.
```

**How to translate from path in Maven repository to Gradle dependecy specification?**

related to [Gradle task to put jars from Maven repository into project lib folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109276/gradle-task-to-put-jars-from-maven-repository-into-project-lib-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency declaration line is incorrect.

> compile "com.oracle.avatar-js:avatar-js:0.10.+"

The repository does not contain an artifact under that name. The group ID should be `com.oracle`.

I did a quick test, and the following line works:

> compile "com.oracle:avatar-js:0.10.25-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: +25 Yes, it also looks like there is no way to specify dynamic version for maven snapshots.